# Cannot get fbi or Plymouth to work with Jessie Lite on a Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspbian-jessie, plymouth

I am using an OctoPi Jessie Lite image and need either a Plymouth boot screen or just an image on boot screen instead of text logs.

I installed Plymouth using:

```
sudo apt-get install plymouth plymouth-themes
sudo apt-get install pix-plym-splash
```

and adding `quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles` on the same line of /boot/cmdline.txt. I then ran `sudo plymouth-set-default-theme spinfinity`
after reboot nothing shows up; just a white flash (like in camera flash) and then I get tty login / automatic login text and then **Octoprint-tft** starts up

So, I removed Plymouth:

```
sudo apt-get remove plymouth plymouth-themes
```

I tried using fbi using this [link](http://www.raspberry-projects.com/pi/pi-operating-systems/raspbian/custom-boot-up-screen) but even then the same white flash for milliseconds and automatic login then goes to Octoprint-tft.

There is an error message while I use boot screen (Plymouth or any other)
the message is:

```
bcm2835-aux-uart 3f215040.serial:could not get clk -517
```

The plymouth screen works on HDMI cable and monitor of my desktop but not showing up in Wondershare 3.5 inch LCD (B).